# Change git url in weblate

Tags: weblate

We have changed the server where our repositories are hosted. So now we have to change the url where weblate is pushing and pulling the changes from the repository.

We host Weblate ourselves and I am a weblate admin. Can you tell me where I can change the git url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Administration interface, Component settings, you can find that on `/admin/trans/subproject/` URL.

Comment: in weblate v5.0.2 the url is _`/admin/trans/component/`_.

Comment: In Weblate 5.0 you go to Manage / Settings menu at the component, no need for Django admin interface.